# Delete a record from a table depends in the other table value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

Hi I am new to sql I am still learning any advice or help I will really appreciate it.

I have two tables: first table (tbl1) will only show the list of id and description, and the second table (tbl2) lists all the cx using the id. The column id of tbl1 has common value in tbl2 (`tbl2.address` references `tbl1.id`). I am trying to delete record in tbl1 id where the status in tbl2 of that id is Done only.

```
tbl1

id     |       description
-------+----------------------
addA   |         address A
addB   |         address B
addC   |         address c


tbl2 

id        |    address    |   Status    
----------+---------------+-------------
jk1ii     |     addA      |   using
hhh9      |     addA      |   pending
ajjdia    |     addA      |   done
jhis99    |     addB      |   done
ajduio    |     addC      |   using
```

Desired output for tbl1

```
id    |  description
------+-----------------
addA  |    address A
addC  |    address c
```

only addB will be deleted because no other cx using the address unlike addA and addC there is still someone using the address so it will not be deleted is it possible ?

right now I am using this query

```
DELETE from tbl1
WHERE id  in (select address FROM tbl2 WHERE status ='Done')
```

however the output is wrong it will delete addA even there still some cx in tbl2 is using it

Comment: You could just add a condition to your WHERE clause: AND id NOT IN (SELECT address FROM tbl2 WHERE status != 'Done'), though not as elegant as answer below.

Comment: Thank you for help I really appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below query:

```
DELETE from tbl1
WHERE id  in (select address FROM tbl2 group by address having sum(case when status='Done' then 0 else 1 end)=0)
```

Comment: Hi you are genius its working would you mind how did you do it? Thank you

Comment: thank you :) you need to just set logic for selecting data from your second table